# Deploying Applications to Bluemix

Tags: db2, websphere, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to deploy the J2EE Module only into Bluemix? Because what I did now is I deployed the entire whole WebSphere Application Server. But then, what happen is that I can't run the application locally anymore because the server.xml configuration has been changed to use the database service selected in the Bluemix platform.
Here's a snippet of the current setup. If there's another way, can someone tell me how

[image: Setup]

Comment: Yes, just drag the application to the Bluemix server, not whole server or add it to Bluemix via `Add and Remove ..` option.

Comment: @Gas yeah, I did that but when I tried to visit the app url. There were some issues, like for example, it can't locate the database that Bluemix uses; Db2 . For that reason, I deployed the WAS instead of the web module because it is where the configuration of the database is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish EAR and web modules directly to the Bluemix server in Eclipse.  The Tools also support incremental publish of both type of modules.

To deploy the application, you can simply right click on the Bluemix server on the Servers view and select the *Add and Remove* option.  For details, you can refer to *Publishing an EAR file* section of the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#eclipsetools). The steps for publishing a web module is the same as publishing an EAR module.

Note that publishing the module directly does not allow you to include Liberty server configuration, i.e. the server.xml, as part of the publish operation. In case your application require specific server configuration settings, then you need to continue to publish the entire server as before.

Comment: I want to confirm something, if I used a database service in Bluemix, I need to configure the app so that it uses the service that I chose in Bluemix, right? Since, my WAS contains the configurations on what database to use, then I need to publish the entire WAS server, not the application alone only. Just like what the image above shows. Correct?